# Why won't the loop, loop?

Tags: python, loops, break

I'm writing code to just generate the first 1000 primes and I don't understand why this code won't loop as is.

```
divisor = 1
guess = 2
count = 0
while count < 1000:
    divisor+=1
    while guess%divisor==0:
        if guess==divisor:
            print(guess)
            guess+=1
            count+=1
            divisor=1
        else:
            guess+=1
            divisor=1
```

If I add break to the end of the if and else definitions (as shown below), then the loop runs fine as below, but I can't understand it.

```
        if guess==divisor:
            print(guess)
            guess+=1
            count+=1
            divisor=1
            break
        else:
            guess+=1
            divisor=1
            break
```

Comment: Could you explain "won't loop"? What exactly happens without the breaks?

Comment: @mbratch: My guess is that without the breaks, the inner `while` loops infinitely. This is to be expected, as OP assigns `divisor` to `1`, making `guess%divisor` to be `0` no matter what `guess` is

Comment: For those who read my previous comment, ignore it. Both if and else resets divisor to 1. So yes, the inner loop will loop infinitely.

Comment: You don't need inner `while`, see our correction below.

Answer (score 0):

your loop runs fine, 1st time `guess==divisor` is true so it prints, after the fisrt time it enters the `else` block

change:

```
else:
    guess+=1
    divisor=1
```

to

```
else:
    print("else ",guess)
    guess+=1
    divisor=1
```

and you will see that is running fine

Answer (score 0):

Apparently.the condition :

```
guess%divisor==0
```

is always true..becauese you make:

```
divisor=1
```

on both if and else statement

however the "break" is to jump out of the while loop.so in the second situation ,your code works fine.

Answer (score 0):

**Corrected:**

```
divisor = 1
guess = 2
count = 0
while count<1000:
    divisor += 1
    if guess%divisor==0:            #'while' was replaced by 'if'
        if guess==divisor:
            print guess
            guess += 1
            count += 1
        else: guess += 1
        divisor = 1                 #moved here
```

output:

```
2
3
5
7
11
13
17
...
7841
7853
7867
7873
7877
7879
7883
7901
7907
7919
```